# Sitecore powershell - Display values in the dropdown list with duplicate values

Tags: powershell, sitecore

I have a hash table with keys as Guids and values as string. Of which some of the values are same with different Guids. I'm trying to display values in the drop down list but I'm getting Guids/keys instead. Is there a way to display values which are strings(and have duplicates) instead of Guids?

```
$options = [Ordered]@{}
Foreach ($i in $Items) // $Items contains list of items
{
 $options +=@{i.Id = $i.DisplayName}
}
```

$options.keys is displaying all the guids
$options.values is displaying the names. However when I try to display them to allow users to select an input, I'm getting Guids in the drop-down list

```
$props = @{
    Parameters = @(
    @{
       Name = "Name"; Title = "Name"; Options = $options
     }
    )
}
```

Displaying in the dialog Using:
`$name =Read-Variable @props`

Comment: Is the `DropDown` a `ComboBox` or a `ListBox` ? You need to be more specific. Please add the `DropDown` code and how you're adding the hashtable to it.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon - Read-variable is displaying dropdown of $options as in Example 1 https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/appendix/common/read-variable

Comment: No idea how that module works but as it seems from examples you would need to use the strings as Keys and GUIDs as values to get your desired output.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon - It is a hashtable. So cannot use string as keys as it contains the duplicate values

Comment: I know that, you can make one Key return multiple GUIDs (values).

Answer (score 1):

`Read-Variable` uses hastable keys as dropdown labels and hashtable values as dropdown values. It makes sense, otherwise users will not know which item they select when seeing duplicate names in the list.

You should make your hashtable keys unique in order to use them with `Read-Variable`. For example, you can replace `$i.DisplayName` with `$i.FullPath` (assuming you have unique paths in the content tree) or append date of creation to the item name like `"$($i.Name) $($i.Created)"`.